# Better configurable products - also load the related products

Tags: magento, module

We are using the Magento module DerModPro_BCP (Betterconfigurable Products).

We have configurable products based on simple products. Some of these simple products have related products.

When selecting a configuration option, the related products of the assigned simple product should be loaded.

What is the right approach to add blocks to reload when changing options?

Answer (score 2):

The extension renders the full simple product during the AJAX request and extracts the necessary data via Xpath queries from the generated HTML. Then it sends this data to the browser where CSS queries are used to replace the content in the page

1. Create a new module with a following `config.xml`
2. In the node `global/bcp/update_selector_list` add a new node `<related />`
3. In `default/dermodpro_bcp` add `<update_related_....` entries to defined the Xpaths and CSS paths

In addition, `catalog/product/list/related.phtml` has to be modified in your theme to contain an empty `<div>` as a placeholder, if no related products are defined.